# Where to ask embed vs link HTML in email

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a place on Stack Exchange where I can ask the following:

Let's say your company sends its customers quotes. In the quote it has some fancy images, logos, and HTML/CSS to help sell the quote to the customer.

The problem: When you embed the HTML/CSS into an email, you are working at the mercy of the email provider to render the HTML/CSS correctly. First, different email providers will render your quote differently. Second, you have a subset of HTML/CSS to work with.

A workaround is to attach a PDF of the quote and also link the quote externally so a browser opens it. The body of the email may look like this:

> Your quote is attached.
>
> Additionally, you may [click here](http://example.com) to view your quote.

**The question is,** would there be a huge loss in views since people willing to open an attachment or click on an external link may be less? And where can I find data to support the conclusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to optimize your so-called ['conversion rate'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_marketing#Conversion_rate), and our site [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com) deals with these kind of topics; it has [157 questions](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conversion+or+conversion-rate) about conversion and conversion rates. Maybe it has already been asked; if not, please check their [help center](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting. Note in particular that *implementation* questions, e.g. asking how to implement the HTML/CSS so that it looks good in all/most email clients, is off-topic (this isn't mentioned in their help center, but it's one of the standard close reasons there).

Comment: Thank you sir or Ma'am. I can never tell with elves.